# Where can I find a video clip of a mechanical FP shutter in operation?

Tags: presentation, shutter, teaching, clubs

I am about to give a presentation on the basics of exposure for the newcomers in our photo club. When talking about the shutter, I'd like to show the actual operation of the mechanism. There are a few instructional videos available in YouTube that explain the theory in length, accompanied by animations of the process. However, I need just short clip of the real thing in slow motion.

The best thing I could find so far is [this](http://regex.info/blog/2008-09-04/925) famous 'video' by Marianne Oelund. The problem, as you can tell, is that it is not really a video, and the mouse interaction is required.

Can anyone point to a clip in this style — but a real video?

Comment: I notice that the video on that site was put together from a series of stills. Unfortunately the originals aren't online anymore, but maybe the originator would make them available on request. It'd then be easy (and, heh, off topic) to create a video from those stills.

Comment: Or you could pull them from the animation web page frame by frame and do the same, but that's pushing the envelope of fair use — I'd get permission first, if you're going to present it to anyone.

Comment: @mattdm - thanks, I was thinking about that but given the length of the sequence, I decided it just not worth it for me (not to mention copyrights). At the worst case, I will just make a simple animation in PowerPoint (with the advantage of presenting faster-than-sync-speed as well), but I really wanted to show the real thing.

Comment: So, I ended up doing simple animations in PP, one for slow and one for fast speed. I also linked to the page I mentioned in the question and had manually demonstrated the mechanism. Thanks for the suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Would a video like this serve your needs? It is currently posted on YouTube, an I am not sure that exhibiting it from there is sufficient, or if you need it to be embedded in your own app. Anyway, useful content starts around time index 1:15.

[The Shutter - Photography with Imre - Episode 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=xOTNTdE3MUw#t=77s)

The following video may also be useful, as it is purely a video of an actuating shutter. It is also found on YouTube:

[Focal-plane shutter - Schlitzverschluss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZP1Xxo5cSk&feature=player_embedded)

Finally, this video may also be useful. It is not an *actual* video of an actuating shutter, however it has some very useful animations that demonstrate the concept. It is primarily discussing the effect of flash and flash duration on photography, and how that plays into the length of exposure and the nature of the actuation of the shutter at different speeds.

[Shutter/Flash Synchronization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvZ6VujbhjM&feature=player_detailpage#t=67s)

Answer (score 1):

[The beautiful D3 at 11 fps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG5QedhroYQ&NR=1)

It is at 1/4000s so you can see the sync speed, which causes rolling shutter effect and need for HSS.  It also shows the lens aperture, though the actuator is out of focus.